# Can containers be implemented purely in userspace?

Tags: linux, containers, virtualization

There are a bunch of container mechanisms for Linux now: LXC, Docker, lmctfy, OpenVZ, Linux-VServer, etc. All of these either involve kernel patches or recently added Linux features like cgroups and seccomp.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to implement similar (OS-level) virtualization purely in userspace.

There's already a precedent for this - User Mode Linux. However, it also requires special kernel features to be reasonably fast and secure. Also, it is literally a Linux kernel running in userspace, which makes networking setup rather difficult.

I'm thinking more along the lines of a process that would act as an intermediary between spawned programs and the Linux kernel. You would start the process with the programs to spawn as arguments; it would track system calls they made, and block or redirect attempts to access the real root filesystem, real network devices, etc. without itself relying on special kernel features.

Is such a thing possible to implement securely, and in a way that could be invoked effectively by a limited user (i.e. not privileged like chroot)?

In summary: would a pure userspace implementation of something like LXC be possible? If yes, what would the penalties be for doing it in userspace? If no, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly it turns out the answer is "yes": this is what systrace and sysjail do.

http://sysjail.bsd.lv/

And they are also inherently insecure on modern operating systems.

http://www.watson.org/~robert/2007woot/

So if you want proper sandboxing, it has to be done in kernel space.